# Best methods of catching trigger errors in PostgreSQL (9.1)

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers

In testing newly added triggers to a PostgreSQL database, all works well. However, on the production server, something--very occasionally--crashes the database forcing a restart.

What are the best methods of logging errors/actions to catch trigger errors on the production server in PostgreSQL?

TIA

Comment: "crashes the database". Um. Details? How exactly does it "crash"? What is in the PostgreSQL logs? Is the version of the production DB different?

Comment: @CraigRinger "crashes the database" as in the postmaster does not respond to any further requests. I had to reboot the computer. To this newbie, where are the "logs"? Thanks.

Comment: @CraigRinger The development version is 9.3, the production version is 9.1. Thanks.

Comment: re: "where are the logs": http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/11/dear-postgresql-where-are-my-logs.html

Comment: Do *not* develop on a different version to what you run in production on.

Comment: @CraigRinger The idea of "updating" a perfectly functioning installation is not that appealing to me :(

Comment: Then you'd better install 9.1 on your dev environment. Otherwise you will have a *bad* blowup at some point when you deploy something to production. Would you develop and test on Windows 8 then deploy to Windows Server 2003 with no interim testing?